# Pass html file as a route in perl dancer2 MVC framework

Tags: perl, dancer2

I have a file on my machine at /abc/assets/file/

I want to return this file as a route. It is possible to do that ?

Comment: Hmm, you can not return a file as a route. Route is an [url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (web address) for the file/resource. Dancer2 [route handlers](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual.pod#Route-Handlers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically do that outside Dancer in your PSGI file with a different Plack application that's mounted in the same PSGI file. Have a look at [Plack::App::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::App::File) for an individual file, or [Plack::App::Directory](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::App::Directory) for an entire directory.

Your PSGI file would then look something like this.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";

use MyApp; # this is Dancer2-based
use Plack::Builder;
use Plack::App::File;
use Plack::App::Directory;

builder {
    mount '/' => MyApp->to_app;
    mount '/abc-file' => Plack::App::File->new(
        file => '/abc/assets/file')->to_app;
    mount '/foo' => Plack::App::Directory->new({ 
        root => "/xyz/foo" })->to_app;
};
```